# Attaching files to email using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro to automatically generate and send emails out to a list of addresses while attaching a specific file to each.
Still being a bit green to coding in VBA I have "kitbashed" the below but am having trouble working out how to get the file path to read properly.

```
Sub Send_Files()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim FileCell As Range
Dim rng As Range

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set sh = Sheets("List")

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
    Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:C1")

    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Curent Week Supplies"
            .Body = "Good Morning" & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
                & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Please find attached this week's CWS file." & _
                vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "If you have any queries concerning this then please feel free to contact us." & _
                vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Best regards"

            For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                    If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                        .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                    End If
                End If
            Next FileCell

            .Send
        End With

        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

Set OutApp = Nothing
With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

When the macro tries to attach the file it gets stuck with this: -

```
For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                    If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                        .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                    End If
                End If
            Next FileCell
```

[image: Excel data in used for macro]

Comment: What do you mean it "gets stuck"? Does it loop but never do anything, does it throw an error, etc.?

Comment: `Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:C1")` - in your comment you say columns C-Z - It looks like you're just looking at column C?

Comment: Hi BruceWayne, the macro throws up an error and stops in the line .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value. The error advises that the file path cant be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?:

```
Sub Send_Files()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim FileCell As Range
Dim rng As Range

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set sh = Sheets("List")

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each cell In sh.Range("B1:B" & sh.Range("c1048576").End(xlUp).Row)

    'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
    Set rng = sh.Range("C1:C" & sh.Range("c1048576").End(xlUp).Row)

    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Curent Week Supplies"
            .Body = "Good Morning" & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
                & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Please find attached this week's CWS file." & _
                vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "If you have any queries concerning this then please feel         free to contact us." & _
                vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Best regards"

            'For Each FileCell In sh.Range("C1:C" &     sh.Range("c1048576").End(xlUp).Row)
            'If IsEmpty(FileCell.Value) Then Exit For

             .Attachments.Add cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            'Next FileCell

            'Take a look before send
            '.display

            .Send
        End With

        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

Set OutApp = Nothing
With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Raul. This update to the code has got the Macro to run. Many thanks for your input. When the Macro runs it is producing the emails as expected but each email has all the files in the list attached. How do i get the macro to only attach the file on each line to the email address on that line? I have attached an image of the excel sheet i am working on near the top.

Comment: Yes, actually i just comment the "for  each FileCell", please see try with this code!!!!  i hope this works for you!

Comment: The update to the code is now working exactly as required. Many thanks for your assistance